# Erro ao conectar no SQL Server utilizando pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server

Estou tentando conectar ao banco de dados do SQL Server utilizando a lib pyodbc em Python, porém estou encontrando erro logo de início.

Segue o código e o erro abaixo.

Script:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver = {SQL SERVER Native Client 11.0};'
'Server = DESKTOP-3TFNKAR;'
'Database = Aula1;'
'Trusted_connection = yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''

CREATE TABLE Professor (
    Nome varchar(100),
    Idade varchar(10),
    Email varchar(100)
)

''')

conn.commit()
```

Erro:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver = {SQL SERVER Native Client 11.0};'
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados n�o encontrado e nenhum driver padr�o especificado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Eu fiz a modificação de `'Driver = {SQL Server};` para `'Driver = {SQL SERVER Native Client 11.0};` como tentativa, pois pelo o que eu entendi o meu driver é esse.

Enfim, eu sou bem iniciante, portanto explicações também são bem-vindas.

Agraço desde já!!

Comment: Oque resolveu para mim foi fazer a instalação do SSMS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16 Ele fez a instalação de tudo que era necessario para conectar no banco de dados, após isso funcionou corretamente pelo python.

Comment: Oi Vítor, obrigada pela contribuição. Eu mudei o driver de conexão, conforme @Ricardo Pontual comentou abaixo e resolveu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string sem espaços, e também confirme se tem o driver instalado:

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=DESKTOP-3TFNKAR;DATABASE=Aula1;Trusted_connection=yes');
```

Para visualisar melhor:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL SERVER Native Client};
                       Server=DESKTOP-3TFNKAR;
                       Database=Aula1;
                       Trusted_connection = yes;');
```

Se quiser testar com `ODBC` driver, pode mudar o driver para `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`.

Note que, o ODBC às vezes requer registrar o nome da fonte de dados usando o **"ODBC Data Source Administrator"** no Windows

Comment: Resolveu a mudança do driver para o que você sugeriu. Muito obrigada!